# html route values not being passed to the url/controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

the title pretty much says it all

here is the controller action method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string Name, string isType)
        {
            if (isType != null)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Index","ProductsController", new { type=Name });
            }

            var categories = await _context.Categories.
                Where(c => (c.ParentCategory == Name)).ToListAsync();


            return View(categories);
        }
```

here is the html trying to route to the controller

```
   @* @("~/img/"+item.CategoryName+".jpg") *@
            <a asp-action="index" asp-route-name="@item.CategoryName" asp-route-isType="@item.IsType">
                <text>@item.CategoryName</text>
            </a>|
```

model definition

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public string Imgfilepath { get; set; }

        public string ParentCategory { get; set; }

        public string IsType { get; set; } 

    }
```

the strange thing to me is that the item.CategoryName getts passed fine but the isType attribute does not appear to be passed as it is always null when i check in the debugger.

Comment: where you define isType and categoryName ?? show model

Comment: i linked it but I don't see the model definition is relevant.

Comment: Check IsType value set properly or not

Comment: On view, your using item model, that item model IsType property is set or not ?

Comment: and one more thing, you don't need to write ProductController, you can just type Product in RedirecToAction method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196272/discussion-between-mangesh-auti-and-samuel-wakeman).